# Multiple inclusion of the same image gives huge PS file

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, pdf, postscript, dvi-mode

I am using `beamer` and having included the same image many times with `pgf`, declare once and insert.

It looks like the PS file from `dvips` grow linear as I create slides (the image is on the background). Reading online this should not be a problem on Unix systems, but the on windows it might be an issue.

Anyone have a solution as compiling takes around 1min now and the PS file is 200mb, not that handy?

How its used currently:

```
\pgfdeclareimage{redtree}{images/red_tree}%
\setbeamertemplate{background}{%
\pgftext[at=\pgfpoint{30mm}{\framesep-0.22\framesep},base,base]{\pgfuseimage{redtree}}
}
```

Comment: The PGF manual is not completely clear on this, but my inference from the way it is phrased is that the reuse of an existing image only makes a difference to file size for PDF output.  As you're using PS, it may be that the image is reincluded for every use.

Comment: Is it a vector image (original EPS) or a raster image (which might have been converted to EPS)? AFAIK there is a way to define a PostScript macro which is reused every time. Is there a specific reason why you are using PS and not PDF? With PDF it is not an issue.

Comment: I am using PDF, but first dvips+ps2pdf. I just dont want that large ps file at every compile point for other reasons, speed, google drive uploads it every time ect.  The pdf file is way smaller 20mb.

Comment: I think @AndrewStacey is correct that it somehow includes the image for every use, but as I am showing in my question, first declare and then use, i dont know why it does this.

Comment: The original eps image are a vector object.

Comment: You can compile directly to PDF using `pdflatex` which is now the standard way (at least IMHO). You can convert your (E)PS images to PDF using `epstopdf` and other tools. There are even automated packages which do this for you now.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. As your say, its your opinion, and I favor latex over pdflatex(or to refine, i dont use pdflatex).

Comment: Doing this in postscript looks somewhat complicated.  I found http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/PostScript_FAQ#How_to_place_several_copies_of_a_picture.3F which seems vaguely relevant.

Comment: It's so long since I did this I'm adding this as a comment rather than an answer, someone else may want to fill in the details but basically if you insert ps literal specials and the file inclusion (perhaps in the document preamble) so the postscript ends up `/mypicture {...contents of ps} def` then instead of the usual pdfile special you need a ps literal that just does `mypicture`

Comment: Is the result same with using `\includegraphics{}`? Probably image declaration is not working for your particular file. Either converting it to `.png` or using `pdflatex` looks like the remaining options.

Comment: Accepting that it was not a trivial question, i made it such the ps file is created in a temp folder not syncing to cloud services instead of finding a proper solution.

Answer (score 13):

The problem with including the same PostScript graphics multiple times is very well
explained in chapter "16 Including An EPS File Multiple Times" of

> Keith Reckdahl, "Using Imported Graphics in LaTeX and pdfLaTeX", 2006,
>   URL: http://mirror.ctan.org/info/epslatex.pdf

The trick is that the original PostScript file is split in two parts. A header
file for dvips loads the graphics data somehow in PostScript's memory and
the actual PostScript image file is a small one that only loads the previously
stored graphics file. The second file again gets included multiple times, but
the file size is smaller, because the larger graphics part is only written once.

That makes a small PostScript size. But the PDF file is probably large, because
the PDF generating application would have to recognize that the same graphics
is included multiple times.

The reusing feature of PDF works with "form XObjects", they can be generated
via `pdfmark` operators. The downside is that PostScript viewers are not too
happy with this. The pictures that are loaded as XObject are not shown.
However the PDF file will contain the picture only once and the file size
is small.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike `pdftex` and `xetex`, the `dvips` back-end does not detect multiple inclusion of the same file on its own, and the `\special{psfile=...}` is inserted over and over again into the DVI file, leading to code replication of the multiply embedded image file in the intermediate PostScript and finally in the target PDF.

This can be remedied, as pointed out by Heiko Oberdiek, by creating a PDF Form XObject from the image once during the `ps2pdf` conversion step and insert references at the places where it is to be repeated. This has been implemented in the [**`xsavebox`**](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xsavebox) package. The intermediate PS (small in size) does not show the repeated image, but PS converted back (big again) from the PDF displays them all correctly.

Using http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/base/doc/images/tiger.eps (78,815 Byte)

--> PS: 241,428 B ; 228,002 Byte of target PDF:

```
\pdfoutput=0
\documentclass[multido=true]{standalone}

\usepackage{xsavebox} %embed content only once
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multido}

\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}

\xsavebox{Tiger}{\includegraphics[width=5in]{tiger}}%
\multido{}{400}{\xusebox{Tiger}}
%\multido{}{400}{\includegraphics[width=5in]{tiger}}

\end{document}
```

while

```
\multido{}{400}{\includegraphics[width=5in]{tiger}}
```

--> PS: 31,676,394 B ; 13,063,945 B of target PDF