# How do I use same figure multiple times?

Tags: graphics, pdf

Is there a way to use same figure multiple times -- without reinserting it? That is I don't want to pay it's weigth several times in the output pdf file.

I remember I saw someone telling `adjustbox` can do it,  but I can't find it in its manual.

Comment: AFAIK the `graphicx` package does this for you. Just include it with `\includegraphics` as many times as you need, it will be just once in the PDF.

Comment: @Daniel: That's cool. Probably You right.

Comment: @Daniel: This is not the case for `dvips` + `ps2pdf`. The `xsavebox` package can be used here to include the external PS only once . See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/296122 .

Comment: @AlexG: Good catch, thanks! I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `\includegraphics` command offered by the `graphics` and `graphicx` packages already does this. Technically, the included image is placed only once in the resulting PDF and each additional instance just is a reference to the already embedded object.

Interestingly, this topic is not mentioned in the package documentation of these packages. (At least I was just not able to find it there). I learned it from the manual of the `beamer` class (§13 Graphics, page. 130), where Till Tantau writes about PGFs graphics commands:

> Like `\pgfdeclareimage`, `\includegraphics` also includes an image only once in a .pdf file, even if it used several times (as a matter of fact, the graphics package is even a bit smarter about this than pgf)

However, ultimately this image folding feature  depends on the `graphics`/`graphicx` backend driver, which is determined by the employed TeX/LaTeX engine: While it works out of the box with `pdftex`, `xetex` and `luatex`, images are included multiple times if going the `dvips`+`ps2pdf` route. For this case, user AlexG has suggested a [workaround in another answer.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/296122/3751)

Comment: isn't there a spelling error? `\includegraphicx` vs. `\includegraphics`?

Comment: I have tried using the the `dvips` route with the famous `tiger.eps`. Unfortunately, it seems that the PDF file size scales linearly with the number of inclusions of tiger. Even with `ps2pdf -dMaxInlineImageSize=0`.

Comment: @AlexG I tried with `pdflatex`, sice it struck my curiosity. Document with no image is 63 kB (`\includepackage{lipsum}`), with one `figure` environment it's 3 pages and 170 kB, with two environments it's 3 pages and 170 kB, with 4:4pg/170kB, 5:5pg/171kB, 6:5pg/171kB, 7:6pg/171kB, 8:6pg/172kB, 9:7pg/172kB, 10:7pg/172kB. So the PDF size scales, but not really linear with the number of included (same) images :)

Comment: @Habi: Well, I forgot to mention that the slope is approx. 1 in the case of `dvips` + `ps2pdf`.

Comment: @AlexG you mentioned that the "file size scales linearly", which is slope = 1 in my understanding `:)`

Comment: Adddendum: The magic is in the driver `pdftex.def`

Answer (score 2):

With pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX, repeat `\inludegraphics{...}` as often as desired. For these engines, the `graphicx` package already makes sure that a graphics file is included only once, and that references are inserted at other places.

For `latex` ->`dvips`->`ps2pdf` this is not done automatically and the final PDF will contain multiple instances of the same included file. This can be avoided by means of the `xsavebox` package:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xsavebox} %include content only once
...
\xsavebox{img for frequent use}{\includegraphics{example}}%
\xusebox{img for frequent use}
...
\xusebox{img for frequent use}
```

This method can still be applied to the other engines listed above, because it may reduce compilation time.