# Performing arithmetic on multido variable in PSTricks

Tags: pstricks, multido

I want to take an image and display it in PSTricks several times side by side, rotating it by the same amount each time.  I want to use the multido command - something like

```
\multido{\i=0+1}{10}{
\rput{\i * 10}(\i,0){Image}
}
```

but I can't figure out how to multiply the variable `\i` by a constant in the braces that specify the rotation angle.  Since I only need simple integer multiplication, I assume I don't need any heavy-duty packages like `fp`, as LaTeX has this ability built in.  I think it should be easy to do using PostScript - something like

```
(!\ia 10 mul)
```

but I can't figure out the syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It must be `\iA\space mul` otherwise the space between `\iA mul` is "eaten" by TeX's parser and you'll get a wrong expression like `3mul` without the space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,multido}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\multido{\iA=0+1}{10}{%
    \rput{!10 \iA\space mul}(\iA,0){\includegraphics[width=1cm]{tiger}}%
}       

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To avoid multiple image inclusion with `dvips`+`ps2pdf`, you could give [`xsavebox` a try](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/296122).

Comment: or `usepackage{graphicx-psmin}`

Comment: @Herbert: specifying the rotation angle with  `{!10 \iA\space mul}` doesn't work on my system. It's not the first time I notice using postscript code in parameters does not work. Do I miss something?

Comment: No it should work. For _old_ systems you have to enable `\SpecialCoor`

Comment: Your code didn't compile on my system (TexShop 3.61 on OS X Yosemite version 10.10.5), but if I put it inside of a `pspicture` environment and add `\SpecialCoor` then it works.

Comment: `\SpecialCoor` is only needed for old PSTricks packages. The `pspicture`  environment is only needed if you want to reserve the space.

Comment: Why does the TeX parser eat the space between `\iA` and `mul` but not the space between `10` and `\iA`?

Comment: (BTW, any reason for the two empty `%` comment symbols?  I see that @Bernard used one too)

Comment: @Herbert: I have the very latest version for MiKTeX (2.64b) from 2/7/2016 and I didn't have to specify `\SpecialCoor` for  years!

Comment: @tparker: TeX sees a `\` and scans the next tokens. If it is a letter then it scans  all following characters until it sees a non letter. The space is handled in a special way, it is "eaten" by TeX. It is not easy to explain it in more deatils in a comment. Read the TeXbook or TeX by Topic.

Comment: @Bernard: if you have an up-to-date system then `{!10 \iA\space mul}` will work. If not create a small example and show the file versions.

Comment: @Herbert: I finally found out the error: `\space` was wrongly placed. However, I think it would be nice to have the possibility to write things more or less like the `algebraic` option of `pst-plot`.

Answer (score 2):

You also can use  commands from `pst-fp`:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node, multido}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}



\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}
\psset{unit =0.6}
\multido{\i=0+3}{10}{\pstFPmul{\angle}{\i}{10}%
\rput{\angle}(\i,0){\psellipse[linecolor=red](0,0)(0.5,1)}
}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]