# How to pass an algebraic expression with \pstAngleAOB to RotAngle?

Tags: diagrams, pstricks, pst-eucl

I attempted to assign `\i*\pstAngleAOB{A'}{T}{B'}/10` instead of manually-calculated value `\i*16.626` to `RotAngle` as shown in the following example (see the commented rows).

#### MWE

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-geometrictools}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\usepackage{pst-calculate}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\def\offset{30}
\begin{document}    
\foreach \i in {0,...,10}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid,linewidth=2pt](-6,-4)(6,7)
    \pstGeonode(0,3){T}(-4,0){A}(4,0){B}
    \psset{PointName=none,PointSymbol=none}
    \pstRotation[RotAngle=-\offset]{T}{A}[A']
    \pstRotation[RotAngle=\offset]{T}{B}[B']
    % --------------------------------------------------
    % I don't like the manually-calculated value 16.626
    \pstRotation[RotAngle=\pscalculate{\i*16.626}]{T}{A'}[U]
    % I want to use the following but it does not compile.
    %\pstRotation[RotAngle=\pscalculate{\i*\pstAngleAOB{A'}{T}{B'}/10}]{T}{A'}[U]
    % --------------------------------------------------
    \pstArcOAB{T}{A'}{U}
    \psCompass{}(T)(U)
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

How to pass an algebraic expression with `\pstAngleAOB` to `RotAngle`?

Note: In order to know whether there are elegant tricks or built-in macros available in other drawing packages (Asymptote, TikZ, Metapost, etc), feel free to submit with those packages.

Comment: From my understanding pstAngleAOB works at PS level while pscalculate works at LaTeX level, so you can't pass the angle to LaTeX, but you can (somehow?) compute the expression in PS or compute the angle in LaTeX.

Comment: I guess it would be something like `RotAngle={\pstAngleAOB{A'}{T}{B'} 0.1 mul \i \space mul}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of RotAngle is directly used as PS code:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-geometrictools}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\usepackage{pst-calculate}

\def\offset{30}
\begin{document}    
\pgfforeach \i in {0,...,10}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid,linewidth=2pt](-6,-4)(6,7)
    \pstGeonode(0,3){T}(-4,0){A}(4,0){B}
    \psset{PointName=none,PointSymbol=none}
    \pstRotation[RotAngle=-\offset]{T}{A}[A']
    \pstRotation[RotAngle=\offset]{T}{B}[B']
    \pstRotation[RotAngle={\pstAngleAOB{A'}{T}{B'} 10 div \i\space mul}]{T}{A'}[U]
    \pstArcOAB{T}{A'}{U}
    \psCompass{}(T)(U)
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Remark: Because all pstricks do is to generate PostScript code, and the PostScript code is basically run after TeX has finished, there's no way for TeX macro to access the value of PostScript-computed results. So you have to either compute all the coordinates in TeX (difficult), or compute the compression `angle/10*i` in PostScript (demonstrated in this answer)

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297856/performing-arithmetic-on-multido-variable-in-pstricks for the reason why `\space` is necessary.

Comment: @user202729: Not really true. We can write PostScript values into a file and using it later in a second TeX/LaTeX run. Just like column widths in a longtable are calculated.